# Convert Date Format?

Tags: powershell, date

Is there a way, besides string manipulation, to change the format of the output returned by my function get-epochdate below?

My goal is to have a date that looks like 2018/01/13 13:08:00 instead of 01/13/2018 13:08:00

Code Example:

```
$global:starttime = 1516129987054

$EpochDateDiv1k = $global:starttime / 1000

Function get-epochDate ($epochDate) { [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($epochDate)) } 

$global:ConvertedStartTime = get-epochdate $EpochDateDiv1k
```

Comment: `[DateTime]` object does not have format. If you need string in particular format, then you need to convert `[DateTime]` to string.

Comment: have you seen this writeup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692801(v=technet.10)  u looks to be the closest to what you are looking for.

Comment: I have seen that article, thank you. However, I'm not sure how to apply get-date with what I'm doing in my script currently.

Comment: As @PetSerAl noted, `[DateTime]` is an object. If you need string output, you can use string formatting to output it in whatever format you want.

Comment: $global:ConvertedStartTime = (get-epochdate $EpochDateDiv1k).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')

Comment: Although to be honest, depending on what you do with that variable in the rest of the script I would leave it a DateTime object for as long as possible.

Comment: If the reason behind this question is that the date needs to be sortable, consider to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date/time notation: `(get-epochdate $EpochDateDiv1k).ToString('s')` which results in: `2018-01-13T13:08:00`, see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Sortable by what? If you mean a textual sort somewhere else, then yes. Keep in mind that `Sort-Object` can sort `[DateTime]` objects without converting them to text first.